# shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not working

Tags: android

In my application, **shouldOverrideUrlLoading**() is not called on  4.0.3 version. I have tested it on 2.2 and 4.0.1 and they all are working fine.
Device name is **HTC verizon**.

My intent is to provide custom activities for mailto: and tel: links present in the page. Any ideas on how I can make this work if shouldOverrideUrlLoading() is never hit?

Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

Autoexplicative method, you should override onPageStarted too:

```
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

    // 11 = Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB (Android 3.0)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {

    // According to this page:
    //
    // http://www.catchingtales.com/android-webview-shouldoverrideurlloading-and-redirect/416/
    //
    // shouldOverrideUrlLoading() is not called for redirects on
    // Android earlier than 3.0, so call the method manually.
    //
    // The implementation of shouldOverrideUrlLoading() returns
    // true only when the URL starts with the callback URL and
    // dummyCallbackUrl is true.

         if (shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url)) {
             view.stopLoading();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you try the worksarround removing the < 11 api level line? I Noticed you are having the problem on > 11, so try and if works, make an if for this device.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method instead shouldOverrideUrlLoading()

```html
 private static WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new webviewclient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }
public class webviewclient extends WebViewClient{

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(request.toString());
        return true;
    }
```